# Peering Connection between GKE and EKS

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

Is it possible to connect a GKE cluster to a VPC within AWS? For this specific use case, I want the GKE cluster to be able to talk with the EKS cluster behind a VPC in AWS.

- I have the CIDR block for my GKE cluster `gcloud container clusters describe _cluster_name_ | grep clusterIpv4Cidr`
- I've already created a VPC and cluster in AWS (i.e. I have a VPC ID for my aws VPC)

Do I need to create a VPC for my GKE cluster in addition to the VPC for my EKS cluster, or do I just need the CIDR range for the GKE cluster for AWS?

Google searching renders very few results for connecting clusters from different providers.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's possible with VPN connection. At first, I think you should have a look at Kubernetes Engine Communication Through VPN [demo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-networking-demos/tree/master/gke-to-gke-vpn). And then, move to the more close example for your case - [site-to-site VPN between GCP and AWS](https://medium.com/@oleg.pershin/site-to-site-vpn-between-gcp-and-aws-with-dynamic-bgp-routing-7d7e0366036d). In addition, check some Google Cloud Router [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/router/docs/concepts/overview) and [example](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example) for some extra information about networking at GKE.